# Building a URL with parenthesis using Razor

Tags: razor

I ran into an issue where I am trying to create an OData URL in some javascript using Razor.  The page displays an error when I run it.

Here is the example:

```
var personId = 123;    
var oDataUrl = "@Url.Content("~/OData/People")(" + personId + ")";
```

The expected result is:

```
var oDataUrl = "/OData/People(123)";
```

But Razor expects the result of the call to Url.Content to be a function.

I worked around this using a separate variable, but was wondering if there was a different way.

Example workaround:

```
var personId = 123;
var baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~/OData/People")";
var oDataUrl = baseUrl + "(" + personId + ")";
```

The workaround is acceptable, but I didn't know if I was missing something.

I have already tried using @: and <text></text> - anyone that can get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, as far as Razor is concerned, "@Url.Content(...)(...)" is a perfectly valid C# expression. So it's seeing the "(" after "@Url.Content(...)" and considering it part of the C# expression. You should wrap the "Url.Content()" call in "@()" (note the extra parens), that will make it much less confusing for Razor :).

For example, if you had a method "Foo" which returned a Func<int, string> delegate, you might want to call:

```
@Foo(123)(456)
```

Razor can't tell the difference between these cases, so we provide the "@()" escape-hatch to bend Razor to your will :).

Here's a fixed example that should work:

```
var personId = 123;    
var oDataUrl = "@(Url.Content("~/OData/People"))(" + personId + ")";
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, it does, and is the solution I was looking for!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first block you posted doesn't look right, as it has unescaped double quotes in it:

```
var oDataUrl = "@Url.Content("~/OData/People")(" + personId + ")";
```

Did you mean something like:

```
var oDataUrl = "@Url.Content(\"~/OData/People\")(" + personId + ")\"";
or
var oDataUrl = "@Url.Content(\"~/OData/People(" + personId + ")\"";
```

?

Comment: The code is a Razor template generating javascript. It could be re-written as var oDataUrl = '@Url.Content("~/OData/People")(' + personId + ')'; and it would produce the same results.